# How to ONLY disable notifications "The following packages have been kept back"

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have used apt-mark hold to hold back 4 different packages because I don't want them to ever be upgraded.  But is there a way to exclude them from even being checked?  I don't want to be reminded every time I run apt upgrade that "The following packages have been kept back".

Comment: Nope. It will always remind you. Something to get used to.

Comment: Lame.  Ok, thanks for your reply.

Comment: You may wish you are reminded; as the held packages may cause others to be held in due course (ie. number may grow) & you'll likely be unable to *release-upgrade* due to held packages etc... ie. it's knowledge you need to be reminded of as there will be consequences of those packages (*unless they're wallpapers or other packages that don't have a consequence/interaction with other parts of the system*)